# STM32 microcontroller families and environment conditions (F4 vs G4 vs F7 vs H7)

Tags: stm32, noise, emc

I want to refresh some product with old PIC18F and use STM32. New product requirement is 8 UART interfaces, a bit more DMIPS and more memory.
I probably could use STM32F0 or F1, some UART multiplexing or something like SC16IS752, but software and hardware would be more complicated and expensive.

I found that H7 and F7 microcontrollers have enough pins and I can map all pins for communication interfaces without any mess on PCB.

But I never worked with such fast microcontrollers. I can use powerful **STM32H7** 480MHz or 550MHz microcontroller and expect it to work like PIC18F in noisy environment? Or maybe I should choose something less complicated like **STM32G4** or maybe **STM32F1" (and multiplex UART, or add SPI->UART converter).

My biggest concern is susceptibility for environment conditions:

- work in the vicinity of high-power electrical devices like big contactors, circuit breakers
- old inverters (which do not always meet today EMC standards)
- LTE modem module on PCB
- low cost wifi module on PCB

**Questions:**

- are more complicated (like STM32F7) microcontrollers expected to be more susceptible to EMC than simple microcontrollers (like STM32F4)?
- are more modern (G4 or H7 series) microcontrollers expected to be more susceptible to EMC than older microcontrollers (F series)?
- shall I worry about microcontroller stability at all (in my case, which is migration from 8-bit PIC18F)?

(let's assume that board is correctly designed 4-layer board)

Comment: It's a 480 or 550 Mhz MCU, but that doesn't mean you *have* to run it that fast...

Comment: Re: STM32F1, last I checked many parts in the STM32F family are on allocation due to the global MCU shortage. Suggest to check with ST/your supplier if you're planning to roll  any of these out at scale anytime soon.

Comment: @ricehornet Thanks. I am aware of this. Global MCU problem will not last forever, product design, software development and prototype testing will take few months, so all I need now is 10-50pcs. I have checked major suppliers stocks, it is not that bad on some products.

Comment: @RonBeyer I was thinking about this. Shall I expect big stability improvement after reducing CPU speed to 50-75%?

Comment: What do you mean by "microcontroller stability"?

Comment: Generally, higher end processors are more sensitive to power supply disturbances. But they also run faster. Unsure if you clock them at the same speed. I imagine higher current consumption does lead to more noise immunity. But I wonder whether the difference is even enough to matter. Cardboard blocks a bullet better than plastic, but it isn't going to matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> are more complicated (like STM32F7) microcontrollers expected to be
> more susceptible to EMC than simple microcontrollers (like STM32F4)?

No, if you have a ground bounce or don't regulate the Vcc accurately then you can expect both (or any) microprocessor to have an event upset and possibly lose execution. The way to overcome this is to have proper board design and layout with adequate EMC control. If your worried about transients from high voltage switching, then run an isolated design (which would add expense, but negate a headache).

I've ran high current switching on the same board (50V resistive heaters at +5A) and not had an issue with the F4's and F7's

> are more modern (G4 or H7 series) microcontrollers expected to be more
> susceptible to EMC than older microcontrollers (F series)?

Maybe faster processors would be more susceptible to *fast transients*, but realize that a +100MHz is going to be hard to translate across most PCB layouts and through most capacitors, when compared to slower (say 10MHz transients or lower).

Remember that the processors are generating very large load transients on the order of 10's to 100's of mA when millions of transistors or gpios are switching, the capacitors (with recommended layout) take care of this kind of switching.

In addition, one can actually use a higher clocked processor at a lower clock speed. With the STM32's this is as simple as creating a

> shall I worry about microcontroller stability at all (in my case,
> which is migration from 8-bit PIC18F)?

Not with proper layout and EMC control. Another thing is you can change the clock speeds, the best way to figure this all out is the STM32 cube mx tool (its also great for configuring the software and assigning ports/uarts/spi/usb ect.)